# How to implement responsive width for Drawer MUI v5 component?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI v5, and am trying to make a responsive drawer where for smaller devices it will take up 100% of screen width while for larger devices it should only take 1/3 of screen width. But I have no idea how to access Paper property to modify the actual width and make it responsive.

My code:

```
import { Drawer, styled } from "@mui/material";

const ResponsiveDrawer = styled(Drawer)(({ theme }) => ({
  [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
    width: "33%", // THIS ONLY CHANGES DRAWER WIDTH NOT PAPER WIDTH INSIDE THE DRAWER
  },
  [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
    width: "100%",
  },
}));

export { ResponsiveDrawer };
```

How I use it:

```
import { ResponsiveDrawer } from "./Style";

<ResponsiveDrawer
            anchor="right"
            open={drawer.state}
            onClose={() => drawer.onClick(false)}
        >
            ...
</ResponsiveDrawer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out shortly after posting the question. This involves inline styling using `useMediaQuery`.

```
const largeScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("sm"))

<Drawer
            anchor="right"
            open={drawer.state}
            onClose={() => drawer.onClick(false)}
            PaperProps={largeScreen ? {
                sx: {
                    width: 450,
                }
            } : {
                sx: {
                    width: "100%",
                }
            }
            }
        >
            <CartContent cart={cart} drawer={drawer}/>
        </Drawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div inside the `<Drawer>` or `<SwipeableDrawer>` component like so and control the width of the div through CSS (or emotion/styled, if you prefer).

```
<Drawer ...>
  <div className="container">...</div>
</Drawer>
```

```css
.container {
  width: 95vw; // for mobile

  ... add media queries for rest of the screen sizes here
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really work. If you do this, the div will be placed as Paper component child thus you can't use percentage based value as the % will be based on Paper component.

Answer (score 0):

In their [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/#mini-variant-drawer) (expand the code blow) they give an example how to access the paper CSS, where you could add your width settings:

```js
const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
  ({ theme, open }) => ({
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    ...(open && {
      ...openedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': openedMixin(theme),
    }),
    ...(!open && {
      ...closedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': closedMixin(theme),
    }),
  }),
);
```

They add the same mixin to `'& .MuiDrawer-paper'` in the main drawer css.

So for your responsive drawer you should add this paper selector to your styled CSS (maybe check with the inspector, if its the right one):

```js
const ResponsiveDrawer = styled(Drawer)(({ theme }) => ({
  [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
    width: "33%",
    '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
      width: "33%",
    },
  },
  [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
    width: "100%",
    '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
      width: "100%",
    },
  },
}));
```

More information about customizing nested elements can be found on https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#the-sx-prop.